# File copy slow from desktop

Tags: windows, file-transfer

When I copy a large file like 5GB+ from one server share to another server share using my desktop, why is it so much slower than if I login to the server and copy it to the very same place? I mean I get about 8MB/s copying the file using my desktop and 60-80 MB/s when logged into the server. Why is that? This is Windows 7 and servers are Server 2008 r2.

from desktop copy - My Computer - \servershare\file copy to another server \servershare\file - 8MB/s

logged into server directly - \servershare\file copy to another server \servershare\file - 60+ MB/s

Comment: What operating systems are you using? Are both shares mounted on your desktop? How are the shares mounted (Samba, NFS, AFP)?

Comment: Windows 7 desktop, servers are windows server 2008 r2, no shares mapped on desktop. I just pull up the share in My Computer \\servershare\folder copy file to \\servershare\folder.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like when you use your desktop to copy the file from one server to the other, it is being transfered through your desktop computer:

**Server 1 -> Desktop -> Server 2**

Whereas, when you log in to a server and copy the file directly, it doesn't have to go through your desktop computer:

**Server 1 -> Server 2**

By using a more direct route, likely with faster connections, the second scenario will enable the file to be transfered much faster.

Comment: So that's how Windows 7 works when copying files via desktop? You'd think it would just copy from source to destination without rerouting through the desktop.

Comment: That's how all major operating systems work when copying files, AFAIK.  To be able to initiate a direct connection between servers from the desktop would require the desktop system to know about the network connection between the servers and how to authenticate one to the other as well as having a way to communicate the copy command to the server.  That would be a nice feature, but it's technically very complicated and I don't know of any OS which implements it out-of-the-box.

Comment: If your question of "why is [copying via desktop] so much slower?" has been answered, please accept a best answer.  If not, please explain what else you want to know about how copying works.